# I am receiving this sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError prior submission of dummy user information into the site. How do I resolve this error?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I am receiving an `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError` after execution. I read somewhere that this exception is raised for errors that are related to the database’s operation and not necessarily under the control of the programmer, e.g. an unexpected disconnect occurs, the data source name is not found, a transaction could not be processed, a memory allocation error occurred during processing, etc. But I am falling short on solving this error.

My `__init__.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '5791628bb0b13ce0c676dfde280ba245'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)

# Beware of circular imports
from smashpass import routes
```

A snippet of my routes:

```
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
        user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data, password=hashed_password)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash(f'Hey {form.username.data} welcome!!', 'primary')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('register.html', title='REGISTER', form=form)
```

Lastly, here is the User model:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"
```

And this is the run-time error I receive after submission of the dummy data:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: user
[SQL: INSERT INTO user (username, email, image_file, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('Hilario', 'hnengare@gmail.com', 'default.jpg', '$2b$12$TpOJBUhD/4Kwi5KePltYjOX8rN1GR6NgrL7V5GAYnDqKXgcHoMBMi')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking at all because you preface this with network errors etc. Are you asking how to catch the error?

Comment: Do you already have a database table with schema in your sqlite db? Can you show the schema?  (`.schema user`)

Comment: The simplest guess I can make is that you forgot [`db.create_all()`](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy.create_all) which would come immediately after `db = SQLAlchemy(app)`

Comment: I am looking for a solution to sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError, if it makes sense thanks in advance

Comment: "I understand that this exception is raised for errors that are related to the database’s operation and not necessarily under the control of the programmer, e.g. an unexpected disconnect occurs, the data source name is not found, a transaction could not be processed, a memory allocation error occurred during processing, etc." For removal of doubt here - no. The table does not exist, exactly as it's telling you. No questions - it doesn't exist. If you had extraneous issues like network connectivity, you'd get other errors

Comment: If `db.create_all()` hasn't worked then it could be that you're looking at the wrong schema. But I did want to remove your doubt there - it's not lying to you :) The only way to get such an error would be to make contact with the DB server in the first place. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the comments had suggested that I had forgotten to implement dB.create_all() and that solved my problem. To create the initial database, just import the db object from an interactive Python shell and run the SQLAlchemy.create_all() method to create the tables and database:

```
    Python 3.7.5 (tags/v3.7.5:5c02a39a0b, Oct 15 2019, 00:11:34) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

   >>> from smashpass import db
   >>> db.create_all()
```

Thank you.